# jqplot: How to show label of line chart series

Tags: jqplot

According to documentation, to have names for line chart series you must set 'label' which is under 'series'. Something like:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1,line2], { 
        title: 'XYZVV, Inc.',         
         series: [
                        { label: 'Toronto' },
                        { label: 'Lima' }
                 ],
```

However, I can't make it. Please, check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbeteta/R92tG/96/

There is showing no label for any serie.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the legend to visible:

```
title: 'XYZVV, Inc.',         
series: [
    { label: 'Toronto' },
    { label: 'Lima' }
],
legend: {
    show: true
}
```